# интерактивная карта на Drupal

Tags: html, cms, drupal, карты

Подскажите в чем проблема может быть, карта рассыпалась, по сайту не каких работ и не было, только было просто изменено имя сотрудника в контактах, после карта вся полетела, скрин прикрепляю для хоть какого-то понимания что происходит, благодарен буду за любой совет, подсказку...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ранее было цельная карта Украины и при нажатии на область определенную внизу появлялись сотрудники ответственные за регион.

Comment: Возможно, карта была спрайтом сделана, и слетел `js`/`css`, нужно код смотреть. Или откатить последнюю рабочую версию сайта, а потом текущие изменения поверх нее еще раз внести.

Comment: а подскажите как на Drupal откаты делать?

Comment: это делается на хостинге/сервере

Comment: приведите пример вашего кода, а так получается гадание на кофейной гуще.... бегло посмотрел ваш сайт - сейчас там никакого намёка на рабочую версию, нет ни классов или ид для элементов, ни js, связанного с картой, ни стилей....

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Если вы добавите код вашего модуля (весь код, то есть html/css/php), а также укажите посли каких именно изменений произошел сбой, вероятность получения много возрастет.

Answer (score 4):

Так как у вас нет подробных данных, **исходя из анализа вашего сайта и типичных ошибок:**
Страница контакты - это node/20. Вся логика (js), классы, ид элементов были прописаны в body (что не правильно). был использован фильтр, который позволял выводить всю ту кашу... При изменении поля(изменении данных сотрудника) и сохранении ноды:

**вариант 1)** был изменен формат фильтра (для вас лучший вариант) и он вывел на экран только разрешенное;

**вариант 2)** ваш html-редактор удалил всю эту кашу, оставив только разрешенное согласно его настроек...

**Что нужно сделать?**

1) Попробовать открыть редактирование ноды, установить формат "Full HTML" и сохранить. Если не получилось, сделать п.2.

2) найти архив базы данных (можно попросить у хостера), найти в таблице field_data_body строку entity_type = node, entity_id = 20. Посмотреть какое значение в поле body_format, попробовать выполнить пункт 1 с этим форматом. С поля body_value перенести данные (перед этим подкоректировав их) в поле редактирование, или напрямую в базу в таблицы field_data_body, field_revision_body

3) переделать эту страницу по нормальному, чтобы в будущем таких проблем не было...